# optimise update query function which update more than 1000 records using async

Tags: mysql, node.js, async.js

I have a function to update more than 1000 records based on certain condition. But when i run this function i get `Too many connection` error due to which only half of the  records get update. 
How to make this function run using async ? by which in one go it should update all the records

Code:

```
db.query("select *, date(login) as login_date from userRegister where logout IS NULL limit 10", function (err, user) {
  if (!_.size(user))
    return
var byCatId = _.groupBy(user, 'catId');
var grouppedArray = _.map(byCatId, function(array) {
                                        return _.groupBy(array, 'login_date')
                                    });
var i, j, k
  for (i in grouppedArray) {
    if (grouppedArray.hasOwnProperty(i)) {
      for (j in grouppedArray[i]) {
        if (grouppedArray[i].hasOwnProperty(j)) {
          if (grouppedArray[i][j].length > 1) {
          for(var k=0;k<grouppedArray[i][j].length;k++){
          if(grouppedArray[i][j][k+1]){
          var updatedLogOut = moment(grouppedArray[i][j][k+1].login).subtract(1, 'minutes').format('YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss')
            async.eachSeries(db.query('update userRegister set  logout= ? where userId = ? and catId = ?', [updatedLogOut, 1, grouppedArray[i][j][k].userId, grouppedArray[i][j][k].catId], function (err, updatedLogout) {
                if (err) {
                    console.log(err)
                    return err
                   }
                  if (!_.size(updatedLogout))
                                    return
                                    console.log("Updated Successfully")
                                    return updatedLogout
            })
        }
    }
    }
                }
      }
    }
  }
})
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per [docs](http://Docs:%20https://caolan.github.io/async/docs.html#eachSeries) first argument is iterable object. you can pass all array of query which has to updated as first argument and the function to handle each item when its executing.

Updated code, not tested.

```
var queries = []
var i, j, k
for (i in grouppedArray) {
    if (grouppedArray.hasOwnProperty(i)) {
        for (j in grouppedArray[i]) {
            if (grouppedArray[i].hasOwnProperty(j)) {
                if (grouppedArray[i][j].length > 1) {
                    for (var k = 0; k < grouppedArray[i][j].length; k++) {
                        if (grouppedArray[i][j][k + 1]) {
                            var updatedLogOut = moment(grouppedArray[i][j][k + 1].login).subtract(1, 'minutes').format('YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss')
                            queries.push([updatedLogOut, 1, grouppedArray[i][j][k].userId, grouppedArray[i][j][k].catId])
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}


    async.eachSeries(queries, 
        function(item, done){
            db.query('update userRegister set  logout= ? where userId = ? and catId = ?', item , function (err, updatedLogout) {
                done(err)
            })
        })
```

Hopes it will help

Comment: Thanks a ton, Works perfectly :)